# Postgres database has high read IOPS, tmp disk usage and memory usage

Tags: database, postgresql

Our Heroku Postgres database has been struggling over the last few days. Queries are sporadically very slow. Here are some charts outlining key metrics:

[image]

Notes on each chart:

- Read IOPS: our database maximum is 4000; does not include write IOPS which is consistently very low
- Tmp Disk Available: temporary storage available
- Memory (postgres): amount of memory being used by Postgres in kB
- CPU Load Avg: CPU utilization percentage (CPU usage divided by the number of available CPUs);

Hardware:

- PostgreSQL 12.14 (Ubuntu 12.14-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, 64-bit
- 8 CPU's
- 61 GB RAM
- 4000 PIOPS
- 500 connection limit
- 1 TB storage: currently only using 41 GB of that

I haven't been able to identify any problems in New Relic. Any idea what may be happening here and how I can go about resolving it? I'm specifically looking for queries I can run to determine what queries may be causing any of these metrics to spike.

Comment: You need to analyze your workload using the usual tools like `pg_stat_statements` and tune accordingly. You cannot expect an answer with next to no information.

Comment: Also check pg_stat_activity to get an overview of the current activity. The database configuration, see pg_settings, is another thing you have to check.

Comment: Any tips or queries I can run with `pg_stat_statements`? I'm fairly new to the tool.